# `page.goto()` sometimes work but sometimes not

Tags: puppeteer

My code: https://github.com/ItzMiracleOwO/yt-cookier/blob/main/functions/getHeaders.js
So the thing is, `page.goto()` sometimes successfully bring me to the site but sometimes hangs and and stuck at `about:blank`. When it success it returns (resolve) the value but if it hangs it returns nothing.
Here is my testing script:

```js
const cookier = require("ytcf")
const config = require("./credentials.json")
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core")
const fs = require("fs")

let num = 0

async function a() {
    try {
        num = num + 1
        console.log(num)
        // await cookier.login({
        //     email: config.email,
        //     pass: config.pass
        // })
        const url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nP_oofP4h28"

        const c = await cookier.getCookie(url)
        const h = await cookier.getHeaders(url)
        console.log(h)

        ytdl(url, {
            requestOptions: {
                headers: {
                    cookie: c,
                    h
                }
            }
        }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.mp3'));
        a()
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }

}

a()
```

At the first few tries it successfully gives the headers, but if the loop go on, it will soon get stuck. Only `getHeaders` get stuck but `getCookie` wont.
`getHeaders` and `getCookie`: https://github.com/ItzMiracleOwO/yt-cookier/tree/main/functions
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you need. I was not sure if you wanted the whole video or just the audio:

```js
const ytcf = require("ytcf");
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const fs = require("fs");

// Strips a youtube video's audio and saves it as a mp3 file
// parameters:
//   videoId: the id of the video to strip
//   outputFile: the name of the output file
async function stripAudio(videoLink, outputFile) {
  const video = await ytdl(videoLink, {
    filter: "audioonly",
    quality: "highestaudio",
    highWaterMark: 1 << 25,
  });
  const output = fs.createWriteStream(outputFile);
  video.pipe(output);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    output.on("finish", resolve);
    output.on("error", reject);
  });
}

const videoLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nP_oofP4h28";

stripAudio(videoLink, "test.mp3").then(() => {
  console.log("done");
});
```

Comment: Hm we are talking about puppeteer not ytdl at this moment :p

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: page.goto() sometimes leave the page about:blank, i want it to work, thats all

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. What are you specifically trying to do with this script?

Comment: https://github.com/ItzMiracleOwO/yt-cookier/blob/main/functions/getHeaders.js
I am trying to get the request of the url